# Ralis Module and Calling a Static Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, static-methods

I am trying to call static method in Module.

```rb
module CoursesHelper

    include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

    def convert(old_price)
        daily_currency = Rails.cache.fetch('daily_currency', expires_in: 12.hours) do
            CurrencyConverter.get_value # <- static. 
        end
        new_price = daily_currency * old_price
        number_to_currency(new_price.round(-2))
    end

end
```

and I made some class in Rails project.

```rb
class CurrencyConverter
    def self.get_value # <- declared as static
        response = RestClient::Request.execute(
            method: :get,
            url: 'https://api.someapicall........'
        )
        value = JSON.parse(response)["rates"]["etc"]
        value
    end
end
```

and I got this error

```
uninitialized constant CoursesHelper::CurrencyConverter
```

Why is this? 
If this is not a best practice, would you let me know it as Rails way?

**EDIT**

Folder structure

```
├── helpers
│   ├── application_helper.rb
│   ├── courses_helper.rb
│   ├── currecy_converter.rb
│   ├── devise_helper.rb
│   ├── introduction_helper.rb
│   ├── orders_helper.rb
│   ├── posts_helper.rb
```

Comment: Where's that class defined? where's the file? The problem is not the method, the problem is that CurrencyConverter is not being loaded

Comment: Code is fine, either you misspelled something or file structure is wrong like @arieljuod said.

Comment: I added structure.

Comment: I wouldn't put the file inside the "helpers" folder, all the other files are "_helper.rb". The converter doesn't feel right in there. Move it to /app/lib for example, I guess it's just some loading issue.

Comment: Could you show what your file structure for 'CurrencyConverter' is please

Comment: was spelling issue.

Answer (score 0):

The **spelling of the class File.** was wrong. sorry guys.

```
currecy_converter.rb
```

should_be

```
currency_converter.rb
```

After I changed it. work fine. Is name of file also important in Rails? :(